# C++ boost::spirit::karma rule for variants

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-variant, boost-spirit-karma

I have a `boost::variant` in my program that takes types of `double`, `uint16_t`, `std::string`, etc. I'm storing these and I'd like to use `boost::karma` to generate/print them out. I'm new to `boost::spirit`, but I understand it works well with variants. What options do I have to go about this? What would a simple grammar/rule look like to generate one of these? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Simplicity Rules

The absolute simplest example I can think of, showcases how karma can even synthesize an `auto_` rule for your particular variant *on the fly*<sup>**[1]**</sup> :

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>    
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main() {
    typedef boost::variant<double, unsigned int, std::string> V;

    for(auto v : { V{42u}, V{3.1416}, V{"Life Of Pi"} })
        std::cout << karma::format(karma::auto_, v) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
42
3.142
Life Of Pi
```

Easy as pie!

The equivalent in a separate grammar: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d71b67e43b655ec)**

### 2. A more involved sample

A more involved grammar (also **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11bdc678dcde0a6e)**), which shows you how Spirit's Attribute compatibility rules DoTheRightThing™ magically:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

typedef boost::variant<double, unsigned int, std::string> V;

struct gen : karma::grammar<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, V()> {
    gen() : gen::base_type(start) 
    {
        using namespace karma;

        start = my_real | my_uint | my_text;

        my_uint = "The value is unsigned integral value (" << uint_ << ")";
        my_real = "The value is double precision floating point value (" << double_ << ")";
        my_text = "The value is an epos: '" << *quoted_char << "'";

        quoted_char = '\\' << char_("'") | graph | "\\x" << uint_generator<uint8_t, 16>();
    }
  private:
    karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, V()>           start;
    karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, double()>      my_real;
    karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, unsigned       int()>   my_uint;
    karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, std::string()> my_text;
    karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, uint8_t()>     quoted_char;
};

int main()
{
    for(auto v : { V{42u}, V{3.1416}, V{"It's a beautiful day!"} })
        std::cout << karma::format(gen(), v) << "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
The value is unsigned integral value (42)
The value is double precision floating point value (3.142)
The value is an epos: 'It\'s\x20a\x20beautiful\x20day!'
```

`main` could also be written as

```
int main() {
    std::cout << karma::format(gen() % "\n", std::vector<V>{42u,3.1416,"It's a beautiful day!"}) << "\n";
}
```

Which should give you a glimpse of just how versatile the Spirit Parser/Generator framework can be.

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> As long as the auto parser generator trait is present; Spirit provides them for a host of types, including `uint`, `std::string`, `double` and `variant` (but also optionals, vectors, maps, anything that can be adapted as a Fusion sequence etc. etc.)

Comment: Added some nice samples. I'm pretty sure this should help you on your way :) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebe63219dd283ec0)**

Comment: thanks so much for this insightful response! this helped me tremendously!